# How to populate different bootstrap dropdowns using Knockout and jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm trying to get data from database and populate different bootstrap dropdowns.

The table contains the following fields: id, ipAddress, hostName, recordNumber

The Model:

```
function myModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable();
  self.ipAddress = ko.observable();
  self.hostName = ko.observable();
  self.recordNumber = ko.observable();
}
```

The ViewModel

```
function myViewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.ipAddresses = ko.observableArray();
  self.hostNames = ko.observableArray();
  self.recordNumbers = ko.observableArray();
  self.selectedIpAddress = ko.observable("");
  self.selectIpAddress = function (){
      self.selectedIpAddress ();
  }

}

var uri = 'api/items';
var array = [];
$.getJSON(uri)
    .done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            array.push(item);
            self.ipAddresses(array.ipAddress);
            self.hostNames(array.hostName);
            self.recordNumbers(array.recordNumber);
        });
    });
```

The array contains well the data but I don't know how to access the different fields of the table, I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
self.ipAddresses(array.ipAddress);
self.hostNames(array.hostName);
self.recordNumbers(array.recordNumber);
```

Html code of one dropdown:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"data-bind="value:selectedIpAddress"
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" id="dropDownIpAddress" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: ipAddresses">
                      <li><a role="menuitem" href="#" data-bind="text: ipAddress, click: myViewModel.selectIpAddress"></a></li>
               </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sounouk/90grj7ht/)

Comment: can you post sample data what you getting at `item` in `$.getJSON`

Comment: I edited the question and added an example of data.

Comment: You probably need to push the fields onto `listOfItem1` (and 2 & 3). Also, `self` doesn't appear to be defined in the `getJSON`. Your question would be more answerable if you gave us the HTML, the data, and where you expected to see things.

Comment: Second that last comment. In addition, don't post a *picture* of data, post it as part of an actual *repro* (i.e. in code).

Comment: @Jeroen I don't know how to add the data in the code, these should come from the database. I updated the question with a little bit more information and added a JSFiddle.